# google as identity provider and oauth

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, single-sign-on, identity, oauth-provider

Apologies upfront. Fairly confused about Google's identity provider platform. Hopefully I can ask this question in an intelligible way.

Here goes: I'm looking to setup this "platform" as a identity provider where the credentials (email and password), identity verification, 2nd factor login, etc are all managed within google. Then of course use this accross multiple apps for a single login.

What identity provider is this? Is it the "email / password" provider? If so, how is that used in the applications? All I see is google specific api calls for login, etc. I need the aforementioned management but with oauth/oidc workflow in the clients.

How is this possible?

Comment: By single login do you mean users login to each of your apps with the same identity or do you mean once a user is logged in, they don't need to login to use another app (single sign-on - SSO)? Google has two services: Identity Platform and Workplace. Implementing the first use case is easy. The second requires more work in developing your applications.

Comment: Log in with the same identity.  I don't see a way of configuring google identity to manage users but enable same identity logins in multiple apps.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform authentication with Identity Platform, there are three kinds of [auth tokens](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-manage-users#auth_tokens) you might encounter:

**Identity Platform ID tokens** 
Created by Identity Platform when a user signs in to an app. These tokens are signed JWTs that securely identify a user in a Google Cloud project

**Identity Provider tokens**
Created by federated identity providers, such as Google and Facebook. These tokens can have different formats, but are often OAuth 2.0 access tokens.

**Identity Platform custom tokens**
Created by your custom auth system to allow users to sign in to an app using your auth system. Custom tokens are JWTs signed using a service account's private key.

You may refer on below links for more info/concepts and how to guides on Identity Platform: 
[Identity Platform users in projects](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-manage-users)
[Signing in users with OIDC](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc) 
[How-to Guides](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to)